# (Oracle)Does adding filter on master table improve the performance of left join condition between master-detail?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if adding a condition in the left join clause that filters the records on a master table, improves the performance of the left join between Master-Detail tables.

E.g.
I have a Master table MT(ID, TYPE) and a Detail table DT(ID, FK, NAME), The left join would be written like:

```
select MT.ID, DT.NAME
from MT left join
     DT
     on MT.ID = DT.FK
```

If between the results of the left join, I only need the information regarding records of a certain type, lets say MT.TYPE='01', Does adding this condition in the left join clause improve the performance of the query?

```
select MT.ID, DT.NAME
from MT left join
     DT
     on MT.TYPE = '01' and MT.ID = DT.FK
```

Comment: TYPE is an attribute from the MT table, so if you need it add it in the where clause after the left join. It will improve performance if you have an index on the MT table on the TYPE attribute

Comment: @OracleDev Whether the check on `TYPE` appears in the `ON` or `WHERE` clauses should not affect the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @OracleDev, but unfortunately I cannot add it in the where statement, since I need all the records from the master table, not only the ones of TYPE=01.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think what you say is correct, it actually modifies the result of the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it actually does, if the condition is in the ON clause, a record of TYPE != '01' will still be part of the result, but with the value NULL in the Detail Table columns, since the join couldn't be performed. Instead, putting the condition in the where statement, won't return records of TYPE != 01 at all.

Comment: No, that is incorrect.  A restriction on the `DT` table would behave the way you describe, but not on the `MT` table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen maybe there has been a misunderstanding, but adding the `TYPE` condition in the ON clause or in the WHERE statement **DEFINITELY changes the result of the query**, you can see it by yourself in this example I've created: https://pastebin.com/TpMqCAcm

Comment: That link isn't a demo.  Please provide a proper demo link.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's a SQL Script, you can execute it wherever you please.

Comment: [Here is an Oracle demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=30a684950641f5f861cdd65d1c378363).

Comment: @Arevalo0o I misspoke and it looks like you are correct.  But, the issues of where the restriction on `TYPE` appears won't affect the execution plan all that much (I think).  I added a demo link above for anyone else who wants to explore your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Wow thank you so much for showing me dbFiddle, I wasn't aware of this online tool. And yeah, I'm also not sure if there is an improvement at all. Thank you so much for all your time!

Comment: FWIW I believe the behaviour @TimBiegeleisen describes is how this should work. I've filed a bug for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no indices setup on the `MT` and `DT` tables, then in general both queries would be executed using full table scans and both would have similar performance.  The situation where the second query might evaluate faster than the first is where you had proper indices setup, e.g.

```
(TYPE, ID) on the MT table
(FK, NAME) on the DT table
```

In this case, if `MT.TYPE = '01'` were very restrictive, it could greatly reduce the amount of work the database would have to do.  Also, this set of indices would speed up the join operation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim, and indeed, I also think that adding those indexes will improve the query performance. But in the case I only have indexes in the PK and FK of each table, by looking to the execution plan of both queries, it seems that the second query performs less "table accesses" to the Detail table so the cost of the outer nested loop decreases. Do you think this means that database engine is smart enough to perform the master table condition before trying to join the record?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and that might explain your observations.  But, it would depend on the cardinality (read: specificity) of the `TYPE` column.  If many records have a type of `01`, then applying it first might not help.